# Nginx https to http server

Tags: php, http, nginx, https, proxy

I have a PHP application(docker) + nginx. This server I access through https. But my problem is, I have the same application(updated version, same routes) in another server that I don't have an https or a public address. Is it possible for nginx to "redirect" to this new server but using the url of my current application/server until I don't have a public ip?

etc/hosts file

```
172.14.0.3    app   // docker ip
# xx.xx.x.xxx  app   // new server ip


127.0.0.1 my_app_url.com         
# xx.xx.x.xxx my_app_url.com       // this is the new server IP I was testing
```

my nginx file, on the proxy_pass property, I was passing the new server ip

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_app_url.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://app;
        #proxy_pass http://xx.xx.x.xxx;   -> I was testing
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name my_app_url.com;

    ssl on;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhp-2048.pem;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /<app-path>
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://app;
        #proxy_pass http://xx.xx.x.xxx;
    }
}
```

I tried to make these alterations, but I don't know if it's possible and acceptable to do this.

Comment: If the 2nd server is private, how are the two connected?

Comment: I have a MAIN WEB APP, that send and receive requests from my_app_url(https), but I need to test another server IP(http). So what I'm trying to do, it's every request that reaches my_app_url it's redirected to the new server ip, that it's not an https.

Comment: Do you fixed your issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: I just went with the "right" approach and created another server with a public ip. But I didn't succed with my main problem.